# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'chromedriver' using Chromedriver on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Chromedriver with Ubuntu (AWS instance).  I've gotten Chromedriver to work no problem in a local instance, but having many, many issues doing so in a remote instance.

I'm using the following code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'chromedriver'
```

I believe I'm using the most updated version of Selenium, Chrome, and Chromedriver.

Chrome version is:`Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Selenium:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-200:/usr/bin$ pip3 show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 3.141.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: urllib3
```

And, finally, for Chromedriver, I'm almost certain I downloaded the most recent version here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/.  It's the mac_64 version (I'm using Ubuntu on a Mac).  I then placed `chromedriver` in `/usr/bin` , as I read that's common practice.

I have no idea why this isn't working.  A few options I can think of:

1. some sort of access issue?  I'm a beginner with command line and ubuntu - should I be running this as "root" user?
2. mis-match between Chromedriver and Chrome versions?  Is there a way to tell which `chromedriver` version I have for certain?
3. I see that Chromedriver and Selenium are in different locations.  Selenium is in: `Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and I've moved `chromedriver` to: `/usr/bin` .  Could this be causing problems?

Comment: are you using a VM in your mac?

Comment: I think you're using the x64 chromedriver on a 32 bit instance

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu, on an AWS service (EC2).  Which chromedriver should I use?  The options are here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/

Comment: I don't think this is a 32 bit instance.  Here is the version I chose:  Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a (64-bit x86) / ami-0fb0129cd568fe35f (64-bit Arm)

Comment: Am I correct in that this is a 64 bit instance, and I should be downloading the Mac 64 bit version, if I'm using Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (64-bit Arm):

1. Download Chrome: `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
2. Install Chrome: `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
3. If you'll get error run: `sudo apt-get -f install`
4. Check Chrome: `google-chrome --version`
5. Download chromedriver for **Linux**: `wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver_linux64.zip`
6. Unzip chromedriver, install unzip `sudo apt install unzip` if required: `unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip`
7. Move chromedriver to /usr/bin: `sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver`
8. Check chromedriver, run command: `chromedriver`
9. Install Java: `sudo apt install default-jre`
10. Install Selenium: `sudo pip3 install selenium`

Create test file, `nano test.py` with content below. Press CTRL+X to exit and the Y to save. Execute your script - `python3 test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

try:
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")
  s = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  assert s.is_displayed() is True
  print("ok")
except Exception as ex:
  print(ex)

driver.quit()
```

---

Example of using Docker and selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:

1. Install docker, installation steps are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. Start container, using `sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-xenon` command, different options are [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)
3. Open Security Group of your instance in AWS and add TCP rule to be able to connect. You can add only your own IP and port 4444 for Selenium
4. Run test from local

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://your_instance_ip:4444/wd/hub",
                              desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Comment: Sers - thanks so much.  You were the only one who was able to completely answer this question, and it's working now.  My error was a combination of a few things: I had not installed chrome on ubuntu (most obvious error), plus I was not using the linux version of chromedriver.  Thanks again!

Comment: Additionally, there was one line of additional code I had to add to get this working completely, and that was to add an extra chrome option: options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')

Comment: While this code works (sometimes), I still frequently get the following error, which may merit a new question topic: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.70)

Comment: Sers, the new question I have asked, regarding this issue, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673231/chromedriver-on-ubuntu-selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-m

Answer (score 1):

I am running the following on `ec2-ubuntu`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", chrome_options=options) #Give the full path to chromedriver
```

Try it. Incase it doesn't work I will find more of the settings.